# can あいだ / あいだに be used with non-past tenses

Tags: grammar, tense

Last week I learned to use あいだ and あいだに to express things that happen at the same time (are parallel) or things that happen while other are occurring. But I noticed that all the examples on the book (みんなの日本語 - 中級１ - Lesson 8, pp. 82) as well as the exercises and their answers use past tense, like this:

> 電車に乗っているあいだ、本を読んで**いた**。
>
> 食事に出かけているあいだに、部屋にどろぼうが**入った**。

As I understand, in this grammatical pattern あいだ is used sort of like a "while". But can this be used to express things that are happening now or will happen in the future, while others occur? For example, is this correct:

> あなたが映画を見ているあいだ、私は買い物に行きます。
>   (While you watch the movie I will go shopping)
>
> みんなが遊んでいるあいだ、私は働いています。
>   (I'm working while everyone is having fun)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> あなたが映画を見ているあいだ、私は買い物に行きます。
>   みんなが遊んでいるあいだ、私は働いています。

Both sentences are perfectly standard. The structure あいだ(に), is indeed not bound to being used with the past tense.

Comment: What about うちに, can it be used with both non-past and past tense? E.g. 雨が降らなかったうちに、ジョギングやってくりゃ良かった。I wish I went for a run before it started raining.